# Why does DIV width expand from both sides in IE7?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to develop a progress bar. I am going to increase the current position after clicking on the 'Expand' button. It's working perfectly on all browsers except IE7.

But IE7 expands the current position of the `div` from both side.

See this [example..](http://jsbin.com/ejubuk/edit#javascript,html)

Comment: Why don't you use the ProgressBar from JqueryUI?   http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "float:left" as in the following CSS style:

```
.progress {float:left;}
```